How do I describe a pain that courses through the whole body but it happens suddenly?
I'm starting to write something is just a fan fict but I hope to better my writing. English is not my mother language so when it comes to describing this exact scenario is hard for me. This is what I have
'Sara felt her body heavy.Breathing was like a chore for the tengu as she tried to take big gulps of air but it was futile. As she props up with her elbow the general hisses as she feels a sudden ache course through her whole body feeling worse in the middle of her right abdomen'
I'm not happy with what I have rn is disappointing to say the least.

Hi, we can't give critiques here..., but search the web for 'writing advice filter words'. Many online blogs with examples (it's a common pattern with beginning writers). Avoiding the filter words should help.
